# How to filter a list with relevant elements left only

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list1 = range(0,11)
```

I would now like to remove all numbers divisible by a certain other number `n`. Is there a simple way to acchieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use list comprehensions -

```
list1 = [i for i in list1 if not(i%3==0)]
```

[Some reference on list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)